# Angular not resolving variable from prior radio button

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am new to Angular and am using a model for multiPage forms at:  https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

It seems to work great in my little cars model where I select the brand and the filter works so proper models pop up.  After selecting the model, I should be able to grab the options for that model (an array included in the model object).  I can see that I have the right model object and it has the Options array of objects, but in that my ng-repeat on the options did not work, I verified that, while I can resolve the model object, if I try to access any of it's members, it fails.

This html:

```
<label>Next select the model for your Dream Car</label>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="lModel in modelList | filter:formData.brand">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
           <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.model" value="{{lModel}}">
           Bring on the {{lModel.Model}} with options: {{lModel.Options}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<label>Debug model.Model: {{formData.model.Model}}<br></label>
<label>Debug model.baseCost: {{formData.model.baseCost}}<br></label>
<label>Debug model: {{formData.model}}<br></label>
<label>Debug model.Options: {{formData.model.Options}}<br></label>
<label>It's all about these great accessories</label>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="lOption in formData.model.Options">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
           <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.option" value="{{lOption.Description}}">
           Bring on the {{lOption.Description}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Results in this display:

```
Next select the model for your Dream Car
Bring on the Huracan LP 610 Spyder **with options**: [{"Option":"HurricanesDetailing","Description":"Special detailing for your Carolina Hurricanes","Cost":"3200"},{"Option":"FluxCapacitor","Description":"Flux Capacitor for Time Travel","Cost":"26000"}]
Bring on the Adventador LP 750 SuperVeloce Roadster with options: [{"Option":"VolumeTires","Description":"Tires that play loud audio","Cost":"5200"},{"Option":"FluxCapacitor","Description":"Flux Capacitor for Time Travel","Cost":"26000"}]
Debug model.Model:
Debug model.baseCost:
Debug model: {"_id":"Lamborghini:001","_rev":"1-8d0a9b1ed46bd0ec8228cd475de94c84","Model":"Adventador LP 750 SuperVeloce Roadster","baseCost":"125000",**"Options"**:[{"Option":"VolumeTires","Description":"Tires that play loud audio","Cost":"5200"},{"Option":"FluxCapacitor","Description":"Flux Capacitor for Time Travel","Cost":"26000"}]}
```

If you can read thru my attempt to show the html as html and highlight some of it in my debugging ... In the radio button for models, I have access to the Options array.  In the model that is selected, I have the Options array, but in the ng-repeat (and in the debug labels I put in) ... I cannot seem to access the members of the model object (including the Options array).  I'm willing to accept that I'm likely doing something silly here, but it is not at all clear to me what that is.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D):

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D
>
> **value**     string
>
> The value to which the ngModel expression should be set when selected. Note that value only supports string values, i.e. the scope model needs to be a string, too. Use ngValue if you need complex models (number, object, ...).
>
> **ngValue**   string
>
> Angular expression to which ngModel will be be set when the radio is selected. Should be used instead of the value attribute if you need a non-string ngModel (boolean, array, ...).

You're setting the model with `ng-model="formData.model"  value="{{lModel}}"`. So you're effectively stringifying the lModel to JSON, and storing that JSON string into `formData.model`.

As the documentation indicates, what you need is `ng-model="formData.model"  ng-value="lModel"`

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks much.  I missed the distinction between value and ng-value.